# Does Unity IAP/Unity Analytics use Google Play advertising ID?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-advertising-id

Google Play Store now requires declaration of use of advertising ID. My game doesn't have Unity Ads, but it uses Unity IAP which requires Unity Analytics. Does Unity use Advertising ID for these? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here on the Unity forums](https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-13-advertising-id-declaration-required-by-google-play.1314465/).

The answer is NO. Neither Unity Analytics nor Unity IAP reads or sends the AD_ID.

Answer (score 0):

According to this document-

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248?hl=en

Apps that use advertising ID need to have the following in Manifest file-

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
```

If we don't have this line in manifest, we can simply declare that we don't use it.

If you have it, then make sure it is actually required for some functionality, else remove it.